# POST won't redirect to anoter action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, http-redirect

I have this action that will render a form, i also have the post action to receive the data e save it to session and then redirect it to another page. My problem is it's not redirecting, the only thing that happens is that i stay at the same page and my url is changed.

This is my code:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Cadastro model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar realizar o cadastro, tente novamente.");
        return View();
    }

    Session["TVCNome"]    = model.Nome;
    Session["TVCEmail"]   = model.Email;
    Session["TVCFone"]    = model.Telefone;
    Session["TVCUnidade"] = model.Unidade;
    Session["TVCadastro"] = true;

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Apresentacao");
}
```

I Also tried to redirect to an action in the same controller and then to another controller but it also won't work:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Cadastro model)
{
    //Processing

    return RedirectToAction("Redirect");
}

public ActionResult Redirect()
{
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Apresentacao");
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is the Cadastro controller and i'm trying to redirect to Apresentacao

EDIT 2:

My Route configuration:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;

routes.MapRoute(
    "SalvaResultado",
    "SalvaResultado",
    new { controller = "Helper", action = "SalvaResultado" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "BuscaCidades",
    "BuscaCidades",
    new { controller = "Helper", action = "BuscaCidades" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "BuscaUnidades",
    "BuscaUnidades",
    new { controller = "Helper", action = "BuscaUnidades" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{*RedirectUrl}"
).RouteHandler = new RouteHandler();
```

Here is my RouteHandler code, i used an outside source so it won't make it too big: http://pastebin.com/WXy7LYN9

Comment: Did you debug it? Are you hitting the RedirectToAction calls?

Comment: Actually i'm redirecting to another controller, i forgot to show the controller name that i'm working

Comment: Yes, when i try with the first option i hit it, when i try the second i'm i also hit it but i'm not redirected to the `Redirect` action

Comment: Can you show your route configuration?

Comment: My RouteHandler Class will check if the url is valid and then call the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a default route so the helper can't generate the correct URL.  If you don't want to use a default route, create another route for the action you want to redirect and use [RedirectToRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks a lot buddy, i was already loosing my mind over it !

Answer (score 1):

I think your `ModelState.IsValid` property is returning false and hence it is returning the same view.

Put a break point in your code and see why your `IsValid` property is false. May be you did not provide all the required property values of your view model, from your form.

Comment: It shows valid, i reach the redirect in both cases but i get back to the same page but my url changes from `/cadastro` to `/cadastro?action=Redirect&controller=Cadastro` or `/cadastro?action=Index&controller=Apresentacao`

Answer (score 0):

Seams to me it is too late to response but...
This can happen if you are getting to your POST method (ActionResult) through an ajax call.
Ajax method is for partial update by design and, it is not intended for full scale submit method unless you have another available way to leave the page.